# Outputting data separated by tabs to text file

Tags: powershell, format, output

I have a bunch of xml files, in each of these files there could be multiple variants (different language locale codes en-us, en-ca, en-gb etc.) I am new to powershell so I'm probably not understanding several concepts.

I'm able to pull all this information but I'm having trouble outputting it in the format I want. I have tried using `Out-File` and have looked into `Export-Csv` but I'm just not able to get it to do what I want. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the format I want out (the content will be copied into Excel)

```
File Path  |  ar-ae  |  ar-sa  |  cs-cz  |  da-dk
File 1         X        X                 X
File 2         X        X        X        X
File 3                  X
```

So basically I want a table with the headers being File Path and each language code. Then under that I want to list all the files and put an X under each locale that exists in the file.

This is my code

```
if (Test-Path ".\siteIA.txt") {
Clear-Content ".\siteIA.txt"
}

$locales = @(
"ar-ae"
"ar-sa"
"cs-cz"
"da-dk"
"de-at"
"de-ch"
"de-de"
"el-gr"
"en-au"
"en-ca"
"en-gb"
"en-hk"
"en-ie"
"en-in"
"en-nz"
"en-sg"
"en-us"
"en-za"
"es-ar"
"es-cl"
"es-co"
"es-es"
"es-mx"
"fi-fi"
"fr-be"
"fr-ca"
"fr-ch"
"fr-fr"
"he-il"
"hu-hu"
"it-it"
"ja-jp"
"ko-kr"
"nb-no"
"nl-be"
"nl-nl"
"pl-pl"
"pt-br"
"pt-pt"
"ru-ru"
"sk-sk"
"sv-se"
"tr-tr"
"zh-hk"
"zh-tw"
)

$locales = $locales | sort

$header = "Path`t" + $locales

Get-ChildItem C:\Users\tests *.xml -recurse | 
% { 
    $outArray = @()
    $file = [xml](Get-Content $_.fullname)

    $path = $file.ExportedContentItem.path
    $name = $file.ExportedContentItem.name
    $availableLocales=@()

    $out = $path + "/" + $name + "`t"

    $file.ExportedContentItem.ContentItem.Variant | % { 
        $availableLocales += $_.variantCulture
    }

    $availableLocales = $availableLocales | sort

    foreach ($locale in $locales){
        if ($availableLocales -contains $locale){
            $out = "X"
            Add-Content ".\siteIA.txt" "X`t"
        } else {
            $out = ""
            Add-Content ".\siteIA.txt" "`t"
        }       
    }

    Add-Content ".\siteIA.txt" "T"
    Add-Content ".\siteIA.txt" "E"
    Add-Content ".\siteIA.txt" "S"

}
```

Comment: So what is not working in the current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to import the output into Excel later, it's best to simply create a TSV (Tab Separated Values) file. The [`Export-Csv`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849932.aspx) cmdlet can do that for you.

Create custom objects with `File Path` and the locales as properties, and set the all those properties whose names are listed in the `Variant` node to `X`. Then export the objects using a tab as delimiter:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\tests *.xml -recurse | % {
  $contentItem = [xml](Get-Content $_.FullName).ExportedContentItem

  $o = New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
    'File Path' = Join-Path $contentItem.Path $contentItem.Name
    'ar-ae'     = ''
    'ar-sa'     = ''
    ...
    'zh-hk'     = ''
    'zh-tw'     = ''
  }

  $contentItem.ContentItem.Variant | % {
    $o."$($_.variantCulture)" = "X"
  }

  $o
} | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.txt' -NoType -Delimiter "`t"
```